# Alloy assertion does not work as expected

Tags: assertion, alloy, model-checking

Here is my alloy code:

```
one sig Library {
    books: set Book,    // set of the library's books
    patrons: set Patron,    // set of the library's patrons
    circulation: Patron lone -> some Book   // books in circulation
}

// set of books in the Library
sig Book {
}

// set of patrons
sig Patron {
    curbooks: set Book // books currently checked out by a patron
}
```

So I want to add an assert that two Patron cannot currently have the same book. Here is the assertion I came with:

```
assert sameBook2Patrons {
    all disj p, p': Patron | all b: p.curbooks | b not in p'.curbooks
}
```

So when check the assertion with:

```
check sameBook2Patrons{} for exactly 2 Book, exactly 2 Patron
```

Alloy does not find any counter-example. But when I use the run command, Alloy gives me plenty of counter example:

```
run{} for exactly 2 Book, exactly 2 Patron
```

Also, I read that adding a fact with the negation of a valid assertion is supposed to give no instance. I added that:

```
fact sameBook2Patrons {
    not (all disj p, p': Patron | all b: p.curbooks | b not in p'.curbooks)
}
```

When I run the model, Alloy finds valid instance.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: note that using the run command does not produce counter examples but instances satisfying your alloy specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the check command wrongly. To check the assertion `sameBook2Patrons` you should instead use

```
check sameBook2Patrons for exactly 2 Book, exactly 2 Patron
```

i.e, without curly braces. If you put the braces, the assertion to be checked is the expression inside the braces (in your case, empty, which is equivalente to true) and `sameBook2Patrons` is just the name of the command.

Comment: Aha thank you, that was the error. Now, I feel so noob, I guess it's just because I am. Thank you again.